# Retrieving both values from a 2 column ComboBox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form (excel, VBA) where there is a 2 column combobox. When user selects a certain value from the combobox, I want to get the value he selected, and the value associated with the first value (ie. the second column value).

How do I do this? Simply `ComboBox1.Value` returns the value of the first column. `ComboBox1.Value(0)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the column property of the combobox.  It is 0-based so the first column is column(0) and the second column is column(1).

```
Me.ComboBox1.Column(1)
```

Comment: at the end if you want both of them it should be something like this : `Me.ComboBox1.Column(0) & " " & Me.ComboBox1.Column(1)`