# Populate Combobox with Two Text Fields from an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox, userform

I'm trying to get values from 2 cells in an array to populate the text field of a combobox on a userform. The values in the array look like this:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
B  4
```

I would like to make a distinction between B2 and B4 in the combobox text field. The field currently populates like `B`. I would like it to populate with `B 2` instead. This question is partly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042084/retrieve-index-by-values-from-an-array-through-a-combobox) question.

I tried using [this](https://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html) that was linked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867461/can-a-combobox-present-more-then-one-column-on-its-textbox-part) but couldn't get the ListCount property to work. I used [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm) to better understand arrays in a hope that it would provide some insight. I tried [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multicolumn-combo-box.html) approach but it doesn't populate the text field. [WhereInArray](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/return-position-of-element-in-vba-array/) looks like it is more for finding a value and also appears to be unique-value-dependent. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924228/retrieving-both-values-from-a-2-column-combobox-vba) but it seems to get tripped up on the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this data in `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

[image]

Populate your combobox `ComboBox1` like this: Loop through the data and use `.AddItem` to add a combination of both data columns.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Data() As Variant 'array
    Data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B4").Value 'read data into array

    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Data(iRow, 1) & " " & Data(iRow, 2)
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Then you can select your item as follows:

[image]

And you can retrieve the value `B 2` with `Me.ComboBox1.Text`:

```
Debug.Print Me.ComboBox1.Text 'returns B 2
```